# KO ObservableArray update breaks when binding with .sort

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm sorting my `ObservableArray` in the markup thusly,  but for some reason, when I push a new object to the pages `ObservableArray`, this does not update.

```
//store.get('pages') returns an ObservableArray

<!-- ko foreach:store.get('pages').sort(function (l , r ) { return l.pageNumber() < r.pageNumber() ? -1 : 1}) -->
    <markup/>
<!--/ko-->
```

However,  when I remove the sort call,  it catches the array change just fine.
Like so,

```
//works fine,  updates when item pushed to observableArray
<!-- ko foreach:store.get('pages') -->
    <markup/>
<!--/ko-->
```

Any idea for a simple workaround?

*Edits*:

Tried using valueHasMutated(),  doesn't force an update either.

**Workaround:**
  I ended up moving the sort call into a subscription on the observableArray, and it seems to be working fine now,  not sure why though.

Comment: Have you tried putting that sort as a `computed` in your viewmodel? That sort of sort doesn't really belong in the view.

Comment: That didn't do it either, unfortunately.  I did find a sort of end-run solution though,  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store.get` returns an `observableArray` but `store.get(...).sort(...)` returns an array.  You're effectively making a one way binding like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ['foo', 'bar']"></div>
```

Also, although you bind a returned value of a function call, to me it has a code smell that you're coupling your business logic with your view logic.  You have something like this:

```
// View
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.get()"></div>

// Javascript
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.get = function () {
        return ko.observableArray();
    };
}
```

And it works, but from your view, it's unclear what you're doing.  I think a better solution would be:

```
// View
<div data-bind="foreach: stores"></div>

// Javascript
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.stores = ko.observableArray();
    self.get = function () {
        var arr = ["foo", "bar"];
        stores(arr.sort(...));// When you do this, KO updates the foreach binding this is bound to
        return stores;// not that you need to, you can access it from the viewModel.
    };
}
```

Glad you found a workaround but take a minute and plan out your HTML binding structure.  It's the first place I start when I'm creating a new view and it drives how I structure my ViewModel.